# what to use the moment after you die in a game?

Tags: grammar

1. I died

OR

2. I have died

which one should be used the moment after dying in a game?

Comment: If you want to emphasize that the "death" was recent, you could say something like "I just died."

Comment: You could also say, "I am dead."

Answer (score 4):

Either.

In most cases, the choice of a perfect or non-perfect construction is a free one, depending on precisely how the speaker is viewing the events temporally.

"I have died" says that there is a present consequence of the event, whereas "I died" does not: it does not say that there isn't a present consequence, merely that the speaker is choosing to focus on the completed event, rather than on its consequences.

Comment: what could be the present consequence if I were to say I have died?

Comment: First example I can think of is "I have died 5 times in this game, but I will beat it."

Comment: is 'I will beat it' a consequence? doesn't consequence mean bad result?

Comment: By "consequence", I mean that the speaker is putting some focus on what comes after the action (dying) - i.e. the state of being dead. I am not talking about things that come afterwards.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Present perfect is a past action that has an effect on present. So does **I have died** imply that *I wont be able to play again*?

Comment: In the real world, it does imply that, @user82287 (but then, in the real world, nobody is ever in a position to say it). Whether it does or not in the game depends on the rules of that game, I think.

Comment: so by using I've died , the action of dying certainly has an effect on present. If the speaker doesn't want to emphasize on that effect, simple past can work. Even for the actions that occured recently

Answer (score 3):

*"I died"* is common, or even more so, *"I'm dead"*.  Related example:

> Oh no!  I **dropped** my ice cream!

*"I have died"* is grammatically correct, and might be more appropriate, but it sounds a bit too formal to use in such a casual context.  For whatever reason, the perfect tense adds distance between you and the event, as if you are casually remarking on it rather than experiencing it.  Related example:

> Oh dear.  A tiger **has bitten off** my leg.  What a bother!

[Relevant Monty Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYC47DYLq2I)  (warning: strong language, graphic violence)

Comment: Thinking back (a *long* way back! :) to the school playground, I'm pretty sure in the context of games where players were progressively eliminated / "killed off", the normal "claim" was always ***You're dead!***, and the acknowledgement / status report was always ***I'm dead***. Whoever heard of ***Bang, bang! You died!***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But it's not "bang bang, you've died" either.

Comment: Yes @andrew I dropped my phone sounds perfectly normal to me. But I died is intransitive so I thought that might mean at some past time or something.

Comment: @user82287  *"[Expletive]! **I** [expletive] **died** again!"*  is a pretty common expression in my household :)